# Can I use the 3rd parameter of browser.wait() for a "return false" instead of alternative error message?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to find a less complex way to look for a potential pop-up-dialog and either click it away (if it appears) before continuing or just continue.

As context: I have a slider-function for dozens of sliders in my app. Now a few of those sliders pop up a warning as soon as you moved them. For these few sliders I need to confirm the warning, before I can continue, while for all the other sliders I don't have to do that.

My code reduced to my problem (spared all definitions, etc):

```
dragSlider = function(){
    //some code to evaluate if(currentValue === desiredValue){return}
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(slider,{x:10, y:0}).perform();
    warningDlg.isPresent().then(function(toConfirm){
        if(toConfirm){
            confirmBtn.click(); //click the warning away, so I can drag the slider again
        }
        dragSlider(); //recursive call until I have my desired value.
    });
};
```

Now my idea is:

```
dragSlider = function(){
    //some code to evaluate if(currentValue === desiredValue){return}
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(slider,{x:10, y:0}).perform();

    //HERE TO WAIT WITH EXPECTED CONDITION AND RETURN FALSE INSTEAD OF ERROR
    if( browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(warningDlg), 500, false)  ){
        confirmBtn.click();
    }
    dragSlider(); //recursive call until I have my desired value.
};
```

That way I could get rid of `then()` and therefore unnecessary asynchronous execution and complexity.

Any ideas, how I can bring that to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap wait functions with your own custom implemented wait functions and do whatever you want.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I don't understand of it, is how does a wrapped function contribute to make `browser.wait()` return `true/false` instead of `continue/break in timeout error`?

Comment: In the custom implemented wrapper wait function, look for time out and conditionally return false to the caller.

Comment: So kind of a try-catch within a function... catch the timeout and instead of error return false? ... I'm a bit slow today (thank's god it's Friday ;) ). Can you maybe provide a small example of your idea?

Comment: I would suggest to play with this idea in the code and come back with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use promise .then() to handle different Promise states:

```
dragSlider = function(){
    //some code to evaluate if(currentValue === desiredValue){return}
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(slider,{x:10, y:0}).perform();

    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(warningDlg), 500).then(()=> {
       // If wait successful - means warningDlg is present
       confirmBtn.click()
    }, (err)=> {
       // If wait not successful - means warningDlg is not present
       // Just empty function to ignore error
    })

    dragSlider(); //recursive call until I have my desired value.
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortuately it doesn't work for me. One thing is the solution still uses `then()`, so it opens an async task. The other thing is, if there is no `(err)` I get a jasmine timeout on a missing async callback.